# Title Tag Nested inside itself with jQuery PHP Load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a dynamic site that loads only the body when a usr clicks a page. I am trying t change the title tag, but am getting no luck.

HTML:

```
<head>

    // Title tag is contained in the php file
    <?php include (BASEPATH . "includes/widgets/pageTitle.php"); ?>
</head>
```

JavaScript/jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(e) {

    // Page url of destination
    var pageurl = $(this).attr('href');
    var baseurl = "http://localhost/offstreams/";

    // prevent page from loading
    e.preventDefault();

    // Empty info inside the body class and reload new info
    // THIS WORKS PERFECTLY
    $('.body').empty().load(pageurl + " > .body > *");


    //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    // THIS IS THE PROBLEM
    //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    $('title').empty().load(pageurl + "> title > *");


    // Push the URL state
    if(pageurl!=window.location){
        window.history.pushState({path:pageurl},'',pageurl);
    }


    //stop refreshing to the page given in
    return false;
    }
});
```

A Snippet of PHP code:

```
//Band page title tag
if (isset($_GET['member']) && isset($_GET['edit']) && isset($_GET['band'])){
    $band_id = $_GET['band'];
    $sql = "SELECT `band_name` FROM `bands` WHERE `band_id` = '$band_id'";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        $band_name = $row['band_name'];
        echo "<title>" . $band_name . " | " . "Offstreams</title>";
    }
```

An example output on actual load would be **Count to Four | Offstreams**, which is what I want.

When I do the ajax load, the website works, but the title tag gives the default url like **localhost/offstreams/etc...** and the title tag turns into

```
<title>
    <title>Count to Four | Offstreams</title>
</title>
```

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're doubling up on title tags there, the $('title').empty() bit will be leaving the previous ones there.

Try putting the title tags in your initial html:

```
<head>

    // Title tag is contained in the php file
    <title><?php include (BASEPATH . "includes/widgets/pageTitle.php"); ?></title>
</head>
```

And removing them from your php:

```
echo $band_name . " | " . "Offstreams";
```

Comment: `$('title').load(pageurl + "> title > *");` Doesn't load anything. Getting rid of the asterisk loads the information (I think it's always been that way - my bad for not removing it), but it still causes the title tag to be nested.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the reason for outputting the `title` in a loop since there is only one per page, unless I am missing something in your code. Seems like it needs to be outside.

```
if (isset($_GET['member']) && isset($_GET['edit']) && isset($_GET['band'])){
    $band_id = $_GET['band'];
    $sql = "SELECT `band_name` FROM `bands` WHERE `band_id` = '$band_id'";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        $band_name = $row['band_name'];
    }
    echo "<title>" . $band_name . " | " . "Offstreams</title>";
}
```

In regards to your JQuery script, keep this in mind from the [.load() documentation](https://api.jquery.com/load#loading-page-fragments):

> jQuery uses the browser's .innerHTML property to parse the retrieved
>   document and insert it into the current document. During this process,
>   browsers often filter elements from the document such as `<html>`,
>   `<title>`, or `<head>` elements. As a result, the elements retrieved by
>   `.load()` may not be exactly the same as if the document were retrieved
>   directly by the browser.

In other words, what you're doing may not work properly all the time with all browsers. With that in mind, give this a try.

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(e) {

    // Page url of destination
    var pageurl = $(this).attr('href');

    // prevent page from loading
    e.preventDefault();

    // Empty info inside the body class and reload new info
    // THIS WORKS PERFECTLY
    $('.body').empty().load(pageurl + " > .body > *");

    // Give this a try
    $(pageurl).load(pageurl, function() {
        $('title').load('title', function() {
            document.title = $(this).text();
        });
    });

    // Push the URL state
    if(pageurl !== window.location){
        window.history.pushState({path:pageurl},'',pageurl);
    }

    //stop refreshing to the page given in
    return false;
});
```

Comment: You know I never thought about the loop. It was written when I first learned PHP and I always thought that a loop was required for anything dynamic (I don't anymore). But the PHP isn't the problem.

The `$('title').empty().load(pageurl + "> title > *");` is for the dynamic title. The comment above it was for people on the site to know the code that is giving me errors. It works, just not how I want it.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you're expecting the title to be. I also don't understand why you're setting the title on the server side (band name) and client side (href). What is your goal?

Comment: I want the title to load `<title>Band Name | Offstreams</title>` but instead I get `<title><title>Band Name | Offstreams</title></title>`. It's because my original code empties the text from the title tag and then reloads the info inside it (the PHP file). That works fine. The real problem is that it adds another title tag inside the original one.

Comment: The PHP script should be doing what you want already, what is the purpose of modifying the title when the link is clicked?

Comment: The page is not technically reloading. I have a music player that I want on the bottom of the page. So I can't reload without stopping the music. Sooo I load the body content that I want to change. That works, but the title tag doesn't.